# Why is one's reason for voting to close being misrepresented?

Tags: bug, closing, close-reasons

I voted to close a question because it had been asked before, and I ticked the appropriate box for this. But then my name came up on a list of people who had voted to close the question because it was "primarily opinion-based". No: that was not the reason I voted to close it. Why is one's choice of reason being misrepresented?

Comment: they just put the most popular choice out of five; not sure what the exact choice is when the reason votes split 2-2-1 or 1-1-1-1-1

Comment: @WillJagy. Thanks for your explanation. It would then be better to say that people had voted to close "for various reasons", if more than one reason had been cited.

Comment: Saying "various reasons" gives less information about what they might need to change to get their question reopened.  Even though some people might be misrepresented, this method allows some progress toward making the post better.

Comment: @robjohn: OK, then the wording should be "for various reasons, including reason X", where reason X is the one chosen by the present algorithm. Anyway, I prefer less information to false information.

Comment: If you read [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17409/closed-question-banner-contains-incorrect-information-about-the-reasons#comment64579_17409) to the question of which this is a duplicate, you will notice that only those who voted for the reason listed are listed as having voted that way, so no one is really being misrepresented.

Comment: @robjohn: when I click on the question, a yellow-tinted box displays the message (I cut and paste) "put on hold as primarily opinion-based by xxxx", where xxxx is a list of names, including mine.

Comment: @robjohn: That only happens when the closure is overall labelled as "off-topic".  For any other closure reason, it makes it appear that all close voters agreed.

Comment: @JohnBentin: if this is truly different than the [cited original](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17409), then you should edit the question to this effect and it should be reopened.

Comment: Not 100% sure this is a duplicate. The older question is "close vote is misrepresented, this is a bug", the new one is "*why* is it misrepresented?". And TBH I'm interested in the "why" too, because I've already had users angry at me (and four other users at the same time) because I had seemingly voted to close a question as unclear, when in fact the question was clear, but still off-topic (but three other users found the question unclear).